# How to p4 unshelve from Jenkins 2 pipeline groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

I have a Jenkins2 pipeline (groovy) script, and I'd like to be able to (optionally) unshelve a shelf using the p4 SCM. I *think* I need something like this:

```
checkout(
    [$class: 'PerforceScm',
     credential: 'my-p4-credentials',
     populate:
         [$class: 'ForceCleanImpl',
          have: false,
          parallel: [enable: false,
              minbytes: '1024',
              minfiles: '1',
              path: '/usr/local/bin/p4',
              threads: '4'],
          pin: p4shelf,           // <--! this variable is the shelf CL
          quiet: true],
     workspace: [$class: 'TemplateWorkspaceImpl',
         charset: 'auto',
         format: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}',
         pinHost: false,
         templateName: p4branch]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug through the p4-plugin github repo. Basically, this can't be done in one step. Instead, first, we must checkout from p4:

```
checkout([$class: 'PerforceScm', ...])
```

Then, we must do an unshelve operation:

```
p4unshelve resolve: '', shelf: shelf, credential: 'jnsmith-p4-credentials'
```

Works like gangbusters.